# Solr version compatibility with Sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: sitecore-client, solr

My team is planning to install Sitecore 9.0.1. We are using Solr 6.6.2 version at the moment. Due to some solr search issues we are planning to use solr 6.6.3.

Is this Solr version compatible with sitecore 9.0.1 and if we can work with this?

Thanks

Comment: Bear in mind solr up to 6.6.5 has security vulnerability https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-13301 . Better use solr 6.6.6 which have it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, according to Sitecore documentation, Sitecore 9.0.1 is compatible with Solr 6.6.3:

[image]

More information can be found here:
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0227897